# Checking if a directory exists with Perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to check if a directory exists in a UNIX system with Perl.

```
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    my $id = $row[0];
    my $hash = $row[1];
    my $direction = '/home/users/' . $hash

    if(-d $direction){
        print "$direction exists";
    }

}
```

But I get this error:

> Global symbol "$direction" requires explicit package name at
>   Perl.pl line 31. syntax error at Perl.pl line 31, near
>   "){" syntax error at Perl.pl line 35, near "}" Execution of
>   Perl.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Line 31 in this case is:

```
if(-d $direction)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Good job using `strict`! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $direction = '/home/users/' . $hash
```

This line is missing a semi-colon, causing a compile error.

Answer (score 4):

If you ever get a syntax error at the start of the BLOCK (`near ") {"`) of an `if`, `unless`, `while`, `until`, `for`, `foreach` or `when` statement, check if the previous statement is missing its semi-colon (`;`).

Similarly, if you ever get a syntax error at the semi-colon (`near "<something>;"`) of a C-style for statement (`for (...; ...; ...;) { ... }`), check if the previous statement is missing its semi-colon (`;`).

---

If you mean to write

```
f();
if (g()) { h() }
```

but you write

```
f()
if (g()) { h() }
```

Perl thinks you're missing a semi-colon before the BLOCK

```
f()
if (g()) HERE { h() }
```

because the following is valid Perl:

```
f() if (g())
```